# Select and read file in java me

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

How to select file in java me with file selection dialog?
How to read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaME SDK contains the PDAPDemo example application. This contains the source code for a file browser. It's not very robust code but it shows you how to access the file system using the API in [JSR-75](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/)'s a tutorial on mobile development.